# Kotlin expression fun vs normal fun - differences

Tags: kotlin

Let's assume that I have two functions which do the same stuff.

First one:

```
fun doSomething() = someObject.getSomeData()
```

Second one:

```
fun doSomething(): SomeData {
    return someObject.getSomeData()
}
```

Are there any technical differences between expression functions and standard function in Kotlin excluding the way how they look?

- Is compiled output the same?
- Are there any advantages using one instead another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Sơn Phan says, they both compile to exactly the same bytecode.

So the differences are simply about conciseness.  The expression form omits the braces and `return`; it also lets you omit the return type (using type inference as needed).  As the question illustrates, the expression form can be shorter — and when all else is equal, shorter tends to be easier to read and understand.

So whether the expression form is appropriate is usually a matter of style rather than correctness.  For example, this function could be on one line:

```
fun String.toPositiveIntegers() = split(",").mapNotNull{ it.toIntOrNull() }.filter{ it >= 0 }
```

But it's a bit long, and probably better to split it.  You could keep the expression form:

```
fun String.toPositiveIntegers()
    = split(",")
    .mapNotNull{ it.toIntOrNull() }
    .filter{ it >= 0 }
```

Or use a traditional function form:

```
fun String.toPositiveIntegers(): List<Int> {
    return split(",")
          .mapNotNull{ it.toIntOrNull() }
          .filter{ it >= 0 }
}
```

(I tend to prefer the former, but there are arguments both ways.)

Similarly, I rather like using it when the body is a simple lambda, e.g.:

```
fun createMyObject() = MyObject.apply {
    someConfig(someField)
    someOtherConfig()
}
```

…but I expect some folk wouldn't.

One gotcha when using the expression form is the type inference.  Generally speaking, in Kotlin it's good to let the compiler figure out the type when it can; but for function return values, that's not always such a good idea.  For example:

```
fun myFun(): String = someProperty.someFunction()
```

will give a compilation error if the `someFunction()` is ever changed to return something other than a `String` — even a nullable `String?`.  However:

```
fun myFun() = someProperty.someFunction()
```

…would NOT give a compilation error; it would silently change the function's return type.  That can mask bugs, or make them harder to find.  (It's not a very common problem, but I've hit it myself.)  So you might consider specifying the return type, even though you don't need to, whenever there's a risk of it changing.

One particular case of this is when calling a Java function which doesn't have an annotation specifying its nullability.  Kotlin will treat the result as a ‘platform type’ (which means it can't tell whether it's nullable); returning such a platform type is rarely a good idea, and IntelliJ has a warning suggesting that you specify the return type explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Compiled output**

Yes the compiled output will be completely the same

**2. Advantage**

You usually use expression function when the body of a function is only one line of expression to make it a oneliner function. Its advantage mainly about making the code more concise. Imagine instead of all the brackets and `return`, you only need a `=` to make things done.